# Android: Fetch Latitude & Longitude on Long press inside StreetViewPanoramaView

Tags: java, android, maps

I want to find out Latitude & Longitude on Long Press inside ***StreetViewPanoramaView***. I tried to find it with various ways like binding "**com.google.android.gms.maps.StreetViewPanoramaView**" inside xml. Also tried with "**StreetViewPanoramaOptions**" inside java file. But didn't find any possible way.

Please guide me if you have any suggestions!!!

Comment: Seems not possible yet. Ref StreetViewPanoramaLocation 
getLocation() from https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/StreetViewPanorama